Render Graphs in react native
I am working with react-native and expo. I want to visualize data that consists of x and y points in this form [ [x1,y1] , [x2,y2] , [x3,y3] ]. However I cannot find a suitable library in react native to visualize this data as  a line chart or bezier chart.
I have tried react-native-chart-kit however it takes x values as labels on x axis and does not plot the y points relative to x points. I also tried react-native-svg and victory-native and nothing seems to be working correctly or as it is supposed to work.
Can anyone guide me on how i can do that?
All what is needed is to plot one or more line charts on a graph and the y-points should be plotted relative to x-points.
thanks in advance.

Using react-native-gifted-charts in a React Native Project
I recently integrated react-native-gifted-charts into my React Native project and found it to be both reliable and highly customizable. If you're looking for a powerful charting library for your React Native app, I highly recommend giving it a try.
You can find more information and documentation on their official website: https://gifted-charts.web.app/
Ease of Use: The library is straightforward to set up and integrate into your existing project.
Customization: It offers a wide range of customization options, allowing you to tailor the charts to your specific needs.
Performance: The charts are optimized for performance, ensuring smooth interactions and animations.
Here is a basic example to get you started:
import { LineChart } from "react-native-gifted-charts";
    
const App = () => {
const data = [{value: 15}, {value: 30}, {value: 26}, {value: 40}];
return (
    <LineChart
    data={lineData}
    color={'#177AD5'}
    thickness={3}
    dataPointsColor={'red'}
  />
);
};

